# Can anyone use the endpoint URLs in a server less js application?

Tags: javascript, api, security

I have this security fear in JavaScript were exposing the code to the client, to me, means exposing all the URLs that you are calling. Let's say I have an endpoint URL at my serverless application that I call when I need to add points to a certain user after a certain condition. Now, the user has access to the URL as the code is shown to the user. In this case, can the user just see the URL, go to an API client like Postman or Insomnia, and then just make a GET/POST request to the URL without satisfying the condition?

Also, let's say there is an API key that is sensitive and cannot be exposed to the client. In this case, I would put this on the server-side and then make a request from the client to the server to execute the call with the sensitive key instead of just having the key exposed to the client. In this case, can a person just not take the URL and make a GET/POST request to the server?

Any general links/tips to developing secure JS applications would also be appreciated.

Comment: How can it be serverless if there's an endpoint URL? The URL points to a server.

Comment: I think [security.se] would be a better place for this question.

Comment: The general rule is that anything that needs to be protected from the user's eyes must be kept on the server. The client just sends user actions, the server decides how they affect the score. The server calls other APIs if there are API keys that must be hidden.

Comment: Could be the OP is referring to "serverless javascript" model. However I dont see how that would change the validity of your comments @Barmar

Comment: The server has to verify all the inputs. For instance, if you're implementing a card game, the server remembers which cards were dealt to each player, and doesn't let them play a card they weren't dealt.

Comment: So my question should probably be rephrased, but let's say to increase a user's point, or for a user to play a card, I need to make a call to the back end, can the user directly not call the URL that is meant to play their card or increase their point unlimited number of times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always take care of the safety of your backend (endpoints). There is no way to hide URLs that frontend will call. When you create your API, you should think that the only user is the best hacker, and his goal is to crack your backend. The smallest vulnerability makes the biggest damage.

Comment: So, if my frontend URL is supposed to make a call to the backend saying that make a call to a protected URL, I can basically have users that simply instruct the back end?